# MySql with database oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to use MySql with oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource class?

I am trying to do that but getting an exception...

```
   "Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:301)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:221)"
```

where url is,

"String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";"

Comment: I doubt it. Every driver and datasource will be specific for a particular database. But why would you even want to do that?

Comment: Nopes. Cant do that. Oracle JDBC driver understands jdbc:oracle based URI not the mysql based one. By the way what gave you this idea of using an Oracle driver with MySql.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was doing wrong . I was using OracleDataSource class for MySql database but it should be MysqlDataSource(com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource). It is working  fine. If there is an other way to do that then pls, assist me in this regard.